# Saving info while submitting page with GET in PHP

Tags: php, html

```
<form method='get' action='y.php'>
   <div>
     <input type='text' id='txtName'  name='txtName'/>
     <input type='submit' value='submit' id='submit'/>
   </div>
 </form>
 <?php
   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') 
   {
      if (isset($_GET['btnSave'])) {
          $name=isset(($_GET['txtName'])?isset($_GET['txtName']:'');
      //then Logic of insert goes here
      }
  }
?>
```

so before moving to `y.php` the record must be saved.
but I cant get the `$name` value, as action given to `y.php`.
How can I get `$name` which contain value in text box.

if you change the action to this (same/current) page record is going to database without any flaw or error.

Comment: So why not just use `POST`? Also why do you using the `ternary operator` check if the variable `isset` then when assigning the value wrap `isset` around it again?

Comment: As @script47 said about isset - it should be `$name=isset( $_GET['txtName'] ) ? $_GET['txtName'] : '';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using post method instead and change your code accordingly, try this:

```
<form method='post' action=''>
<div>
 <input type='text' id='txtName'  name='txtName'/>
 <input type='submit' value='submit' id='submit' name='submit'/>
</div>
</form>
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      $name=$_POST['txtName'];
     //then Logic of insert goes here
    //redirect to y.php with name value
    echo "<script>window.open('y.php?user=$name','_self')</script>";
       }

             ?>
```

Then use `$nme = $_GET['user'];` to get the value of `$name` in y.php

Comment: Yes boss, This is working fine. great. now it is possible to open this Page separately in new tab/--browser window--.  This is more Interesting. very very thank you man.                                                               _blank - URL is loaded into a new window. This is default
_parent - URL is loaded into the parent frame
_self - URL replaces the current page
_top - URL replaces any framesets that may be loaded
name - The name of the window

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
<form method='get' action=''>
    <div>
        <input type='text' id='txtName'  name='txtName'/>
        <input type='submit' value='submit' id='submit'/>
    </div>
</form>
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') 
    {
        if (isset($_GET['txtName'])) {
        $name=$_GET['txtName'];
        //then Logic of insert goes here
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**I suggest you use method post. You can code like this**

```
<form method='post' action=''>
    <div>
        <input type='text' id='txtName'  name='txtName'/>
        <input type='submit' value='submit' id='submit'/>
    </div>
</form>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['txtName'])){            
    $name =$_POST['txtName'];    
    echo $name;
    }

?>
```

you can use the session if you want make the value use in another file.

I hope that can solve your problem